# Firebase hosting rewrites for Cloud Functions firebase.json not working with multiple environments

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a project with multiple firebase hosting projects set up (for staging and production), and when I add rewrites per the Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function) the rewrite for function /bigben does not work at https://customdomain.com/bigben (both deployed to production and in the emulators)

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "production",
      "public": "build",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/bigben",
          "function": "bigben"
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        },
        {
          "source": "!/@(js|css|svg|jpg|png|gif|ico|json|html)/**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
      // ...
    },
    {
      "target": "staging",
      "public": "build",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/bigben",
          "function": "bigben"
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        },
        {
          "source": "!/@(js|css|svg|jpg|png|gif|ico|json|html)/**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
      // ...
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I set /bigben to use this custom domain (that is already configured in Firebase for hosting/the frontend create-react-app? I've seen removing index.html from the build folder, but isn't that needed for CRA?

Answer (score 2):

I know the docs say your `source` should look like that, a simple path, but it never seems to work for me either.  Change your `source` for bigben from:

`"source": "/bigben",`

to this:

`"source": "/bigben/**",`

After that it should do the rewrite correctly.

Edit:

Also your rewrites are out of order and so all of your source files are being rewritten to index.html.  Here are my recommended changes:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "production",
      "public": "build",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/bigben/**",
          "function": "bigben"
        },
        {
          "source": "!**/*.*",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
      // ...
    },
    {
      "target": "staging",
      "public": "build",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/bigben/**",
          "function": "bigben"
        },
        {
          "source": "!**/*.*",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
      // ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Still getting the You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. (index.html of public: build) after doing this, both after redeploying on production and restarting emulators

Comment: @user2521295 Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! Will try this-- by out of order-- I thought the docs said to add the function rewrites before { source: "**", destination: index.html }? What order should they be in?

Comment: The problem is your third rewrite after your wildcard.  Your second rewrite statement says to rewrite _anything_ that's not `/bigben` to index.html.  It never hits your third rewrite statement, so the visitor can't download your JS/CSS assets (I believe, could be wrong).

Comment: Ahh got it, thank you! Will review the CSS/JS assets rewrite-- it hasn't been a problem so far (as in people have been able to access the site with all correct styling/scripts) but have not tried downloading directly.

Comment: Just tried with those !**/*.* rewrites and it is still showing index.html "You need to enable Javascript to use this app" :-/

Comment: I imagine that message is within a <noscript/> tag meaning that JS in your browser is disabled, there's just not enough information.  Open the individual JS files in your browser and make sure that the code is appearing and ensure JS is enabled.

Comment: The app (frontend) is working as expected, but it shouldn't be serving index.html for those backend functions (/bigben)

Comment: The actual response when doing a GET call to /bigben returns the index.html from the frontend app, so the rewrite to /bigben is not working

Comment: Hold shift and click refresh on /bigben, it could be a cache issue.  The above configuration is lifted nearly verbatim from one of my projects.